# X time more than , X time less than

Tags: systems-of-equations, word-problem

I found problem math in book gmat and physic then i confuse translating about word

In physic book  example 1

A = G gravity on mar
B = G gravity on earth

In problem it said "  A is 6 time less than B  " conclusion equation is " A = (1/6)B "

In Gmat book example 2

"A father age is two and a half times more than his son's age " conclusion equation is 
" father age - son age = 2.5son age " or " father age = 3.5 son age "

Confusion is starting because " in the same way , why in the conclusion equation of example1 is not  "B - A = 6A" or " A = (1/7)B"

That is all my question .please teach me i don't under stand it

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The use of "times more than" and "times less than" is recent and appears to be spread by innumerate journalists who  are vague and confused about proportions,ratios, increments, and decrements. If you have $3$ and I have $6$ then (My  number)$=2\times$ (Your number). But if (My number)$=2 \times >$ (Your number) then I have nonsense. "Times less than" is just execrable.

If somebody says that 2 Euros is 2 times more than 1 Euro, ask them whether 1 times more than 1 Euro is 1 Euro  or 2 Euros. Try not to laugh at their answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can glean from your description (there might be a language issue), I tend to agree that it is confusing.

In English, if one says that $x$ is six times more than $y$, there are indeed two possible interpretations of that:

- $x$ is simply six times $y$: $\quad x = 6y$
- The excess of $x$ over $y$ is six times $y$: $\quad x-y = 6y \quad \Rightarrow \quad x = 7y$

Unfortunately, I don't know of a reliable way to determine which is which without incorporating the context.  If $x$ is said to be $k$ times more than $y$, and $k$ is a relatively large number, then the first interpretation *tends* to be more likely.  But I'm afraid the problem is that the wording is just imprecise, and they should've been more direct.  I understand that that's not very much help in many cases, but I don't think there's an ironclad rule you can apply.